# Baseboard Heater-Trying to identify brand

Tags: heater, baseboard

[image: Baseboard Heater]

Need help in identifying brand of baseboard heater.  One is 8 1/2" tall and other is 10" tall.

Comment: There must be marks somewhere on it. Have you removed any of the covers?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to DIY Home Improvement Martha Mills!

Looks like it might be Sterling. Specifically their [Kom-Pak and Senior](http://sterlingbaseboard.com/Kom-Pak-and-Senior.html) series.

Comment: I did remove all of the components and oddly, there are no markings.  This is part of my bolier/hw system, not an electric baseboard.

Answer (score 0):

Any electrical machine will have a nameplate somewhere with model number and vital information such as voltage and current rating.

Heaters typically do not ugly-up their products by putting the nameplate on the outside, where it would also be vulnerable to being painted over. There must be a cover plate to access the wiring; the nameplate is typically installed behind that.

Comment: This looks to be forced hot water and not electrical.